# Alertdialog pops up even after dismissing it

Tags: android, android-alertdialog

I have same problem that is discussed in this question

[Alert dialog pops up even after dismissing it](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12436370/alert-dialog-pops-up-even-after-dismissing-it)

The thing is when the user enters invalid data and clicks submit button, the failed alert dialog gets opened. I have a button(Continue) on the failed alert dialog, after clicking it I wrote dialog.dismiss(); to make it disappear, so that user can recheck the data and can modify. But the problem is while rechecking & modifying the data if he changes the orientation, then again the failed alert dialog is popping up even without clicking submit button. Please suggest.

here is my code,please helpme....

```
final EditText Name = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editText1);

    final EditText Phone = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editText2);

    final EditText Email = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editText3);

    final EditText Message = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editText4);

    final AlertDialog alertDialog = new AlertDialog.Builder(Contact.this)
            .create();

    alertDialog.setButton("Continue..",
            new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                    // here you can add functions
                    alertDialog.dismiss();
                }
            });

    Submit = (ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.bSubmit);
    Submit.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
        public void onClick(View v) {

            if (Name.getText().toString().length() > 0) {

                if (Phone.getText().toString().matches("^[0-9]{1,10}$")) {

                    if (Email.getText().toString()
                            .matches("[a-zA-Z0-9._-]+@[a-z]+.[a-z]+")) {

                        if (Message.getText().toString().length() > 10) {

                            //Calling async class and sending data to server

                        } else

                            alertDialog.setMessage("msg is tooo short...");
                        alertDialog.show();
                    } else
                        alertDialog.setMessage("Invalid email ID");
                    alertDialog.show();
                } else

                    alertDialog.setMessage("Invalid Number...");
                alertDialog.show();

            } else

                alertDialog.setMessage("Enter the Name...!");
            alertDialog.show();

        }

    });
```

Answer (score 1):

Changing orientation destroys the activity and the restarts by calling onCreate.  You may have to handle this in the overidden onResume() to make sure that the dialog is being cleared. See the activity lifecycle here.  http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html#ActivityLifecycle

Comment: @Override
 protected void onResume() {
     super.onResume();
 alertDialog.dismiss();}

Comment: This would give null. Because at the very beginning of the activity onResume() gets executed and gives error as the alertdialog hasn't been created yet.

Comment: So check for null. Not sure why I got a downvote when my intention was good and forgot about null??

Answer (score 0):

```
alertDialog.show();
```

This is called twice according to your code. Just remove above line from everywhere else and use it once at the end.